# How to find the delay when I reset a password using Microsoft's Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to reset a user's password, but there is a delay when I try the new password, between 1-2 minutes before the new password works. I am using the following endpoint:

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{userId}}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7BuserId%7D%7D)

```
{
    "passwordProfile" : {
       "password": "111111",
       "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell when the new password is ready to use or another more efficient endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graph takes up to 5 minutes in updating/showing the value. What I have used in the past to resolve this is Redis Cache.
When saving the new data (password in your case), save it also in redis for 5 minutes, then when checking, go first to redis, if the value is not there, go to graph.

Comment: not a problem, this is caused by the way that graph database works, it is a distributed database, so it has to update all of the nodes, therefore the delay.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I tried to reset password the Azure AD B2C user's password:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserId

{
    "passwordProfile" : {
       "password": "password",
       "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
    }
}
```

[image]

After resetting the password even, I faced a delay of a minute before the new password worked.

> **Note** that: By default, there is a replication delay of seconds/minute after resetting the password.

- There is a primary in Azure AD which handles the change password(write) and many secondary instances which handles login (read) and so there is a delay after resetting the password to secondary instances.
- In order to sign in and change the password, the user must wait at least two minutes.
- There is no other endpoint available to show when the new password is ready to use.